# Ubuntu 10.04.3 VMware guest - no network access after conversion to older VM format

Tags: networking, ubuntu-10.04, vmware-converter

I created and configured a Ubuntu 10.04.3 VM in VMware Player 3.1.4 and now wanted to deploy it on our VMware server, which is running at version 1.0.4. To do this, I used VMware vCenter Converter Standalone 4.3.0 to convert the VM to a format that is digestible for VMware Server 1.x.

The conversion apparently "worked", the VM booted on the VMware server, however did not have any network access - only the `lo` interface was up, not `eth0`, even though an ethernet device was correctly set up in the VM configuration. Trying `ifup eth0` resulted in the following error:

```
SIOCSIFADDR: No such device
eth0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
eth0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
Bind socket to interface: No such device
Failed to bring up eth0.
```

Removing and re-adding the ethernet device from/to the VM configuration and uninstalling VMware tools from the VM did not change the situation. The same problems are encountered when trying to boot the converted VM in VMware Player on my workstation.

Is there anything I can do to avoid having to completely re-install in a new VM on the VMware server? I'd rather avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the NIC types match up (when possible) between VMware Player & Server. Ideally, you may also want to ensure the MAC addresses match up as well.

Answer (score 0):

Likely the network names from the old system do not exist on the new system. Verify that in VMWare that which network the NICs connect to exist.

Also possible is that during the conversion the MAC address of the NICs have changed, and thus have changed to Ubuntu as well. Does eth1 exist?